# C++ Дружественная специализация шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Не получается сделать класс **some** дружественным.

Класс **some** является дружественным к классу **A** (**some** - класс создатель, только у него есть доступ к конструкторам класса **A**). В то же время класс **A** может создать ещё один экземпляр в функции **foo**. Но, как я понимаю, возникает ошибка именно из-за того, что я его объявляю дружественным и использую одновременно. Или нет?

```
template <class T, class Meta = void>
class some;

template <class T>
class some<T, std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type>{
  // ...
};
```

**Вариант N1**

```
class A{
  friend class some<int>; // error C3856: "some": символ не является классом шаблон

  void foo(){
    some<int> a;
    //...
  }
};
```

**Вариант N2**

```
class A{
  template<class, class>
  friend class some;

  void foo(){
    some<int> a;  // error C2976: some: слишком мало аргументов шаблон
    //...
  }
};
```

**Вариант N3**

```
class A{
  template<class, class = void>
  friend class some;

  void foo(){
    some<int> a;  // error C2079: "a" использует не имеющую определения структуру struct "some<int,void>"
    //...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

В точке определения класса A, определение шаблона some не видно. Поэтому, при любой попытке воплощения получаете ошибку. Решение:

```
 // some.h 
 template <class T, class Meta = void>
 class some;
 template <class T>
 class some<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type>{ // сдесь был забыт typename, хотя старые версии MSVC на него не ругаются.
    // ...
 };
```

Использование:

```
 #include "some.h"
 class A{
   template<class, class>
   friend class some;
   void foo(){
     some<int> a; 
     //...
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположение Chorkov было проверено и оказалось, что класс some действительно не виден в точке определения класса A. Всё бы ничего, но там заголовок был подключен и всё должно было работать. Скачал Clear MEF, почистил кэш, вправил студии мозги и всё заработало!